# Add Variables From Class To An ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, class, arraylist

We are supposed to create 2 .java files. I'm then trying to add all the details from the constructor in the **FakeUser.java** to the ArrayList called *users* in the **ReviewSpammer.java** but can't seem to wrap my head around how to do so?

**FakeUser.java:**

```
public class FakeUser {
private String name;
private int age;
private String location;

public FakeUser(String name, int age, String location){
    this.name = name ;
    this.age = age;
    this.location = location;
}

public String toString(){
    return name + ", " + age + ", " + location;
}
}
```

**ReviewSpammer.java**:

```
public class ReviewSpammer {
    private ArrayList<String> phrases;
    private ArrayList<String> stories;
    private ArrayList<Class> users;

    public ReviewSpammer(){

    }

    public void addPhrase(String newPhrase){
        phrases = new ArrayList<>();
        phrases.add(newPhrase);
    }

    public void addStory(String newStory){
        stories = new ArrayList<>();
        stories.add(newStory);

    }

    public void addUser(Class FakeUser){
        this.users = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: `Class FakeUser` is not how you define a variable of the type FakeUser. `String` is a class and you have no problems using that class, so just do the same with your own class. Hint2: `new ArrayList<>()` creates a completly new list as one might suspect. You want to add to existing lists and not constantly create new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to add one or more FakeUsers to users list?

```
public class ReviewSpammer {
    private ArrayList<String> phrases;
    private ArrayList<String> stories;
    private ArrayList<FakeUser> users;

    public ReviewSpammer() {
        phrases = new ArrayList<>();
        stories = new ArrayList<>();
        users = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addPhrase(String newPhrase){
        phrases.add(newPhrase);
    }

    public void addStory(String newStory){
        stories.add(newStory);
    }

    public void addUser(FakeUser newUser){
        users.add(newUser);
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
ReviewSpammer reviewSpammer = new ReviewSpammer();

FakeUser johnDoe = new FakeUser("John Doe", 22, "New York");
reviewSpammer.addUser(johnDoe);
```

Comment: Thanks @Gorazd ! Yes that was exactly what I was looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your issue right, but if you want to use all Users you have in your App, you will need a container to organize all users.

If will look something link this (just pseudo code):

```
   public class UserContainer {

     private List<User> allUsers;

     //Singelton Constructor for the container

     public addUser(User user) {
     allUsers.add(user)
     }

   }

   //update your FakeUser constructor

   public FakeUser(String name, int age, String location){
     this.name = name ;
     this.age = age;
     this.location = location;
     UserContainer.getInstance().addUser(this);
   }
```

You also should take care of deleting users.

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class FakeUser {

private String name;
private int age;
private String location;

public FakeUser(String name, int age, String location){
    this.name = name ;
    this.age = age;
    this.location = location;
}

public String toString(){
    return name + ", " + age + ", " + location;
}

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FakeUser user=new FakeUser("anupam",20,"delhi");
        FakeUser user2=new FakeUser("lucky",20,"delhi");
        ReviewSpammer rs=new ReviewSpammer();
        rs.addPhrase("phrase");
        rs.addStory("story");
        rs.addUser(user);
        rs.addUser(user2);

        ArrayList<FakeUser> list=rs.users;

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            FakeUser fake=list.get(i);
            System.out.println(fake.name+" "+fake.age+" "+fake.location);
        }


    }

}


 class ReviewSpammer {
    private ArrayList<String> phrases;
    private ArrayList<String> stories;
    public ArrayList<FakeUser> users;

    public ReviewSpammer(){             /*Make the arraylist in constructor, not in the methods below as you did */
        phrases = new ArrayList<>();
        stories = new ArrayList<>();
        users = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    public void addPhrase(String newPhrase){
        phrases.add(newPhrase);
    }

    public void addStory(String newStory){
        stories.add(newStory);

    }

    public void addUser(FakeUser user){ /* Make the array list of **FakeUser** class not of **Class** and pass the object of FakeUser as parameter*/
        users.add(user);
    }
}
```

Here is the working demo of what you wanted. Please let me know if there is a problem in understanding the code. I have explained your mistake in comments.

Comment: Instead of asking to explain your answer if there is a problem; you should explain what you've done :)

Comment: No bother - it just makes things easier for the OP, or any future readers.